# onChange event impacts String length (Sanitizer)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, label, onchange

I am currently working on an input label, which formats and fixes an user input to a correct date-time format. 
Currently, nothing except digits will be formatted to a date.

> For instance: **11302020** => **11 / 30 / 2020**

Now I want to set a range the string parts for day, month, year.
If a user exceeds the limit, the number (or part of the string) will be sanitized.

My function chops the input string into chunks, so I can write the values into a new array. 
However, at the end my chopped array has **a)** *size of 6* and **b)** an *overall char length with blanks of 15*. 
 When I put these conditions in an if-question to save these values in separate parts, it starts saving at a char length of 16, which means, after an user enters the full date and an additional char, which is not what I want with my **(b)**. Can someone help me out?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

// export const dateFormatter = (input) => {
//   return input;
// };

export default function App() {
  const [maskedState, setMaskedState] = useState("");

  const dateFormatter = (date) => {
    setMaskedState(date.replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, " $1 / $2")
      .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1 / $2")
      .replace(/(\d{4})\d+?$/, "$1"));

    const maskedStateStr = maskedState.split(" ");
    const charLength = 15;
    const arrLength = 6;

   if ((maskedStateStr.length === arrLength) && (maskedState.length === charLength)){
    maskedStateStr.shift();
    var day = maskedStateStr[0];
    var month = maskedStateStr[2];
    var year = maskedStateStr[4];

   console.log(day,month,year);
   }

   //console.log(maskedStateStr, maskedStateStr.length, maskedState, maskedState.length)
    
  }

  const handleInput = (date) => {
    const inputValue = date.target.value;
    dateFormatter(inputValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={handleInput} value={maskedState} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: console output]

Answer (score 1):

There are so many issues with that code but I only focus on `react` part of it.

- `setMaskedState` doesn't update `maskedState` immediately so `maskedState` will most likely point to a stale state.
- setting `value` on an input renders it uneditable so you don't even see what you're typing. Use `defaultValue`.

That said you should operate on the `date` value and only set the state at the end of your block to reflect the result. Like:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [maskedState, setMaskedState] = useState(null);

  const dateFormatter = value => {
    let formattedDate = value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, " $1 / $2")
      .replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/, "$1 / $2")
      .replace(/(\d{4})\d+?$/, "$1");

    const maskedStateStr = formattedDate.split(" ");
    const charLength = 15;
    const arrLength = 6;

    if (
      maskedStateStr.length === arrLength &&
      formattedDate.length === charLength
    ) {
      maskedStateStr.shift();
      let day = maskedStateStr[0];
      let month = maskedStateStr[2];
      let year = maskedStateStr[4];
      setMaskedState(`${day} / ${month} / ${year}`);
    } else {
      setMaskedState(value);
    }
  };

  const handleInput = date => {
    const inputValue = date.target.value;
    dateFormatter(inputValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={handleInput} value={maskedState} />
      <pre>
        <code>
          {maskedState
            ? JSON.stringify(maskedState, null, 2)
            : "Not a valid date yet"}
        </code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See the [demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dgg6k1)

Comment: Thank you for the clean code, but now my Input is not automatically formatted ?

Comment: @LaFllamme, updated the answer. Should be fixed now, Good luck.